# Ionic browser version

Tags: ionic3

I’m working under Ionic v3, in my app I have an HTML iframe inside for load a external resource, but this resource give me a error because it says “Your browser version it’s too old”, so, my question is:

What browser and what version uses Ionic? I can change the browser version to make my iframe work well inside my ionic app?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can see compatible browsers with Ionic here:

https://ionicframework.com/docs/intro/browser-support/